# Parse or get multiple key dictionary data from GET request

Tags: django, dictionary, get, datatables

Datatables is sending to Django the following query string parameters:

```
   action:remove
   data[1][DT_RowId]:1
   data[1][volume]:5.0
   data[1][coeff]:35
   data[2][DT_RowId]:2
   data[2][volume]:4.0
   data[2][coeff]:50
```

I can access the values like this:

```
print request.GET['data[1][volume]']
5.0
```

How can I access the key itself as a dictionary and its keys?

For example, I would like to access the value as data[1]['volume']. In addition, I need to access the keys; e.g. get 1 from data[1].

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to parse the keys, yourselves and convert them to dictionary. This could be done quickly using the regular expression module in python.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("data\[(?P<key_one>.*?)\]\[(?P<key_two>.*?)\]")
match = pattern.match('data[1][volume]')
key_one = match.group('key_one')
key_two = match.group('key_two')
print(key_one) # Should print 1
print(key_two) # Should print volume
```

See Python documentation of its [regular expression library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to learn more.

Comment: I was afraid this was the only way. I will hold for sometime if someone suggests other solution. Thanks!